# Can I run this on a usb hard drive on my desktop that is currently running windows xp I do not have enough space to partition my drive?

Tags: usb, external-hdd

Can I run this on a usb hard drive on my desktop that is currently running windows xp I do not have enough space to partition my drive ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run as a live USB, some applications even allow persistence so that you can keep files. It is always recommended to install to a HDD however as you will receive crucial security updates.